# Print rows if condition met, R

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out how to print the rows in my logical data.frame that have a `TRUE`'s in them, example:

DATA:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), X2 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), X3 = c(TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

FUNCTION (not working):

```
t(apply(X = data, MARGIN = 1, FUN =  function(x){x[x == TRUE,]}))
```

I want the `TRUE` check to be applied across each row (`MARGIN = 1`)and then return that row if there is even one `TRUE` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `apply` for subsetting directly. You can use apply to make an logical vector you can then use for indexing. (And really you should avoid `apply` with data.frames unless all the columns are of the same type.) If you really only have TRUE/FALSE values you can do a quick trick with rowSums. If you've saved your data in a data.frame called `dd`, you can do

```
dd[ rowSums(dd)>0 , ]
```

to get all the rows with at least one TRUE. If you wanted to use `apply` to find the desired rows, you could use the `any()` function which checks for at least one TRUE value.

```
dd[ apply(dd, 1, any), ]
```